# How to filter in datagridview on keypress in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, filter, datagridview

I need to filter the product on key press. I have below code but its not working. how to do it?

```
Private Sub TextBox3_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyPress
        Me.Test_LaunchTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.Test_Launch)
        Me.DataGridView1.Visible = True
        Dim dv As DataView
        dv = New DataView(Me.DataSet1.Test_Launch, "(convert([Code Article], 'System.String') like '%" & TextBox3.Text & "%')", Nothing, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
    End Sub
```

But I am getting this error

> System.NotSupportedException: The DataSource property of the containing DataGridView control must be set to a BindingSource.

in this line getting error

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you have is crazy. Every time the user presses a key, you query the database and get the same data you already have, then filter it locally. Don't do that. Query the database once and populate your `DataTable`, bind that to a `BindingSource` and bind that to your `DataGridView`. You should then set the `Filter` property of your `BindingSource` on the `TextChanged` event of your `TextBox`:

```vb
myBindingSource.Filter = $"[Code Article] LIKE '%{TextBox3.Text}%'"
```

Better still, restart a `Timer` on the `TextChanged` event and then set the `Filter` on the `Tick` of that `Timer`. That way, you won't be filtering over and over when the user types multiple characters in a row. You can experiment with the `Interval` so that the user doesn't have to wait too long after they stop typing to see the filtered data but long enough that they can type multiple characters without filtering occurring after each one. Something around 300 milliseconds is a good place to start. I'll leave that to you as an exercise. Note that you'd call `Stop` and `Start` on the `Timer` in the `TextChanged` event and then `Stop` on the `Tick` event.

Comment: Private Sub TextBox3_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyPress
TextBox4.Text = Nothing
Me.Test_LaunchTableAdapter.FillByCustomerLevelMapping(Me.DataSet1.Test_Launch, IDUSER)
Me.DataGridView1.Visible = True
Dim dv As DataView
dv = New DataView(Me.DataSet1.Test_Launch, "(convert([Code Article], 'System.String') like '%" & TextBox3.Text & "%')", Nothing, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
Dim bindingSource As New BindingSource()
BindingSource.DataSource = dv
DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource
End sub

Comment: This code is working but s you mentioned everytime its taking the data from DB.
Could you please tell me how to query the db once and populate the data to datatable in this code
Thank youj